# Arc point tangent

Tags: geometry, shapes, curve, babylonjs

I am trying to make an parametric shape, that have all points tangents.

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#1AU0M4#286

Meaning that if I change the parameters, shape will update with all tangents. For example if I set heightM and widthM parameter to same value it should draw perfect circle shape which is not case now:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#1AU0M4#291

I want also to be able to move red points along y axis, so only x axis should be calculated actually.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and a **specific** question about that code